# Intellij won't see SVN 1.8

Tags: macos, svn, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I have Intellij 13 on Mac (Maverick) and have just upgraded SVN to 1.8 using Macports. When i try to checkout a repo the popup dialog doesn't have 1.8 selected i can only choose 1.7. If i go to terminal and check the version it says 1.8. I have googled this a lot and i thought by specifying the path using which svn in terminal which is "/opt/local/bin/svn" then typing that into the Subversion Configuration Directory box it would let Intellij know where the new SVN was?

Am i missing something?

Comment: Do you have followed the recommendation in http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/12/subversion-1-8-and-intellij-idea-13/? Your description is not so clear about that. But what you describe should work (with SVN Client 1.8 installed).

Comment: yes i followed that thanks and i read to the bottom of the comments where they talk about my issue but don't show a solution. need to find out how to let intellij know the new svn path

Comment: The solution they mention (Michael Bach, June 20): "Mac OS X you need to specify full path to SVN"

Comment: I've tried putting the path into the Subversion Configuration Directory box which is the only path box not the subversion options but it doesn't work

Comment: Well, use: `CTRL-ALT-S > Version Control > Subversion > Use Command Line Client > ...`. The button with the 3 dots should open a file select dialog, there is noted: Select path to Subversion executable. You should try all variations.

Comment: As i put above i am on Mac and I've put the path into the binary which you get using "which svn" but that doesn't work

Comment: @mliebelt if you add the up marked comment as an answer ill set it as the accepted as you were right i was putting the details into the wrong box - thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

Well, use: `CTRL-ALT-S > Version Control > Subversion > Use Command Line Client > ....`

[image]

The button with the 3 dots should open a file select dialog, there is noted: Select path to Subversion executable. You should try all variations.